# Key binding changes caused crash of IDLE on MAC (OSX)

Tags: python, binding, crash, key, python-idle

I downloaded Python 2.7 and launched IDLE. Then I tried to change some of the key bindings. The 'ok' button stopped working in the preferences panel and I had to force quit the app. Now if I try to open the app it will flash in the menu bar and then close straight away. I have tried EVERYTHING - I have reinstalled, restarted, deleted ALL .py files, searched everywhere for some file related to key binding and failed miserably. I am in DESPERATE need of help with this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where did you change the keybindings? In IDLE or through OSX?

Comment: I changed the settings within IDLE. I am sure I know of the problem as i have read a few posts on the web about the EXACT same issue and scenario. The only problem is that the solutions provided were all for Windows operating systems and were to delete the files that are generated by the changes and creation of a custom key set, i could not find said files on my OSX Mac.

Comment: Yeah - sounds like the same issue - can you post a link to the solutions they've described, I'll have a look and see if there's anything you might have missed in OSX that Windows does automatically or whatever.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue4765 &
http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/438328/
Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: Delete HOME/.idlerc/config-keys.def, where HOME or $HOME is the environmental variable pointing to your home directory on the particular system.  I don't know what that is on OSX, but you should be able to display it in a console.